# ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not booting up after 2 days of working

Tags: boot

I recently installed the ubuntu 20.04LTS version on my new nvme SSD. It worked 2 days flawlessly but on the third day, I'm unable to boot into the ubuntu. I tried looking for an answer on google and other platforms but seems like this is something new.
[image]

Error Message

```
[    0.332433] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal
```

I don't wanna go to windows again. Please help me out.

Comment: Looks like this is because of the kernal update. I went to grub more options, selected 5.4.0.42-generic and ubuntu booted up.

Comment: You can remove the offending / nonworking kernel - see e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My problem was the new update of the NVIDIA driver.
I tried many solutions. In the end, this was the best way to solve the problem:

- Login in recovery mode.
- Remove all NVIDIA packages.
- Run:

  ```
  ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
  ```